# MYSQL innodb error when i trying backup my database

Tags: mysql

I have a legacy project on a Windows machine, MYSQL version is really old like 5.5, and because of a table which called wp_web_api_logbak20210315 is too large like over 20 gigabytes that's why I deleted it, becuase I don't know what is the problem of database,that table can't be deleted with 'drop table' command, a entired mysql service was downed while I trying to drop that table with that way, that's why I use an unsual way which deleted a frm file as well as .ibd file, that way works but the issue atm is it can't backup anymore, it always showcases issue like following in its logs, any idea how to resolve this problem, ty so much

```
InnoDB: Error: trying to load index PRIMARY for table web/wp_web_api_logbak20210315
InnoDB: but the index tree has been freed!231014 11:48:11 ERROR] 
Cannot find or open table web/wp_web_api_logbak20210315 from
the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for thetable exists. 
Maybe you have deleted and recreated InnoDB datafiles but have forgotten to delete the corresponding .frm files
of InnoDB tables, or you have moved .frm files to another database?
or, the table contains indexes that this version of the enginedoesn't support .
```